# Which algebra of functions can be represented as $C(X)$

Tags: gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras

I don't know if this problem is known or not, so any information would be appreciated:

Let $\cal A$ be an $\Bbb{R}$-algebra of (not necessary continuous) real valued functions defined on a topological space. I would like to know what is the necessary and sufficient condition that $\cal A$ is isomorphic (as a ring) to $C(X)$ for some Tychonoff space $X$.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like the kind of questions that are investigated in the study of natural dualities, a la Clark and Davey ("Natural Dualities for the Working Algebraist", Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mahematics)...

Comment: If you restrict "some Tychonoff $X$" to "some compact Hausdorff $X$", then the question is answered by Gelfand duality: there must exist a $C^*$-norm on $\mathcal{A}$ that makes it into a Banach algebra. For more general $X$, I think, the question is more difficult. Also, why present $\mathcal{A}$ as a set of discontinuous functions on a topological space? If the functions are allowed to be discontinuous, then why bother with the topology?

Comment: If we say that $\mathcal A$ was functions on $Y$, are you hoping to induce a topology on $Y$ or a quotient to get $X$?

Answer (score 1):

In the article [Algebraic description of rings of continuous functions](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=365&option_lang=eng) 
 you can find an algebraic interpretation of such algebras. the description requires a bit more conditions and it seems better to reference directly to this article.